# Is _access: 'TRUE' mandatory for a public route?

Tags: 8, routes

I want a route to be accesed by everyone (logged in or not).

I removed the requirements and still I was seeing Access Denied.

It worked only when I put `_access: 'TRUE'`. Why is this mandatory? Should not default to public when no requirement is set?

Comment: You can just add the “access content” permission to the route. I would assume core does NOT assume access if not specified; it’s better to deny IMO instead of potentially leave a hole.

Comment: I agree with Kevin. Access is denied by default and needs to be provided. As such, if no access rules are set, access is denied, since Drupal has no rules against which to check whether access should be provided.